# How to order posts by slug using query_posts/ Wp_query

Tags: query-posts

I want to display posts sorted by slug on a page. Is it possible to order posts by slug using query_posts or Wp_query?

Answer (score 2):

In WordPress the post slug is saved in database with name `post_name`, so to sort posts by slug just use: `orderby=name`.

**Edit:**

Here's the example of query:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'orderby' => 'name'
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: You are right Rilwis. But it will only work with custom query and not with Query_posts or Wp_query.

Comment: What do you mean custom query vs query_posts & WP_Query? If you're using query_posts or WP_Query, that is custom query. And you just need to pass `orderby=post_name` as a parameter.

Comment: I tried this too, but it didn't worked for me. Can you give me some example for this?

Comment: Just updated my answer with example. The orderby value should be `name` instead of `post_name`. My fault.

Comment: And note that WP_Query defaults to `'order' => 'DESC'` so you might want to explicitly add `'order' => 'ASC'`.